# Communication between QT desktop application and embedded webkit

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I'm newbie in QT programming. Qt can embed webkit control inside Qt desktop application. Is exists any way to communicate between C++ Qt desktop application and website opened in webkit? For example, I want to load page from site created by our webmaster and get events which occur on this site. Or another example: do facebook authorization via webkit and my QT application should know status.

Regards